# accessing audio files from Google Cloud Storage when using Google Speech

Tags: audio, google-cloud-storage, google-speech-api

I have used this bit of code below to successfully parse a .wav file which contains speech, to text, using Google Speech.

But I want to access a different .wav file, which I have placed on Google Cloud Storage (publicly), instead of on my local hard drive.  Why doesn't simply changing

`speech_file = 'my/local/system/sample.wav'`

to
`speech_file = 'https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/speech_proj_files/sample.wav'`

work acceptably?

Here is my code:

```
speech_file = 'https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/speech_proj_files/sample.wav'

DISCOVERY_URL = ('https://{api}.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?'
                 'version={apiVersion}')


def get_speech_service():
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default().create_scoped(
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
    http = htt|plib2.Http()
    credentials.authorize(http)

    return discovery.build(
        'speech', 'v1beta1', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URL)

def main(speech_file):
    """Transcribe the given audio file.

    Args:
        speech_file: the name of the audio file.
    """
    with open(speech_file, 'rb') as speech:
        speech_content = base64.b64encode(speech.read())

    service = get_speech_service()
    service_request = service.speech().syncrecognize(
        body={
            'config': {
                'encoding': 'LINEAR16',  # raw 16-bit signed LE samples
                'sampleRate': 44100,  # 16 khz
                'languageCode': 'en-US',  # a BCP-47 language tag
            },
            'audio': {
                'content': speech_content.decode('UTF-8')
                }
            })
    response = service_request.execute()
    return response
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why your approach isn't working, but I want to offer a quick suggestion.

Google Cloud Speech API natively supports Google Cloud Storage objects. Instead of downloading the whole object only to upload it back to the Cloud Speech API, just specify the object by swapping out this line:

```
        'audio': {
            # Remove this: 'content': speech_content.decode('UTF-8')
            'uri': 'gs://speech_proj_files/sample.wav'  # Do this!
            }
```

One other suggestion. You may find the [google-cloud](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/) Python library easier to use. Try this:

```
from google.cloud import speech
speech_client = speech.Client()

audio_sample = speech_client.sample(
    content=None,
    source_uri='gs://speech_proj_files/sample.wav',
    encoding='LINEAR16',
    sample_rate_hertz= 44100)
results_list = audio_sample.sync_recognize(language_code='en-US')
```

There are some great examples here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/cloud-client

Comment: The second block of code seems to work well, I just am having trouble accessing anything stored in the `results_list`. It is some object other than a list, that's for sure...doesn't look like json...what is it and how to I break into it? `results_list.response` is coming up empty. Perhaps it didn't actually work.

Comment: I messed with this all day -- I ended up asking another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555694/audio-file-isnt-being-parsed-with-google-speech Thanks again for your help on this. It means a lot.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough  I think what Monica wanted to know is how to access her object in her bucket without making the object public.