# audio file isn't being parsed with Google Speech

Tags: audio, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

This question is a followup to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43532247/accessing-audio-files-from-google-cloud-storage-when-using-google-speech).

The snippet of code below almost works...it runs without error yet gives back a `None` value for `results_list`.  This means it is accessing the file (I think) but just can't extract anything from it.

I have a file, `sample.wav`, living publicly here: https://storage.googleapis.com/speech_proj_files/sample.wav

I am trying to access it by specifying `source_uri='gs://speech_proj_files/sample.wav'`.

I don't understand why this isn't working. I don't think it's a permissions problem. My session is instantiated fine. The code chugs for a second, yet always comes up with no result. How can I debug this?? Any advice is much appreciated.

```
from google.cloud import speech
speech_client = speech.Client()

audio_sample = speech_client.sample(
    content=None,
    source_uri='gs://speech_proj_files/sample.wav',
    encoding='LINEAR16',
    sample_rate_hertz= 44100)
results_list = audio_sample.async_recognize(language_code='en-US')
```

Comment: Note that since the audio file is 15 minutes long, it's not being processed properly in just a couple seconds.  It should take several minutes to complete, at least.

Comment: That's a good point...there is the possibility I'm being impatient.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, that's my fault from the last question. That's the `async_recognize` command, not the `sync_recognize` command.

That library has three recognize commands. `sync_recognize` reads the whole file and returns the results. That's probably the one you want. Remove the letter "a" and try again.

Here's an example Python program that does this: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/transcribe.py

FYI, here's a summary of the other types:

`async_recognize` starts a long-running, server-side operation to translate the whole file. You can make further calls to the server to see whether it's finished with the `operation.poll()` method and, when complete, can get the results via `operation.results`.

The third type is `streaming_recognize`, which sends you results continually as they are processed. This can be useful for long files where you want some results immediately, or if you're continuously uploading live audio.

Comment: Hummm...I tried the script with all 3 flavors and none returned anything. I'll try it again though on Monday. Thanks!!

Comment: Since the audio file is 15 minutes long, the only API that will work is the async one, because of the [usage limits](https://cloud.google.com/speech/limits).

Answer (score 1):

I finally got something to work:

```
import time

from google.cloud import speech
speech_client = speech.Client()


sample = speech_client.sample(
      content = None
    , 'gs://speech_proj_files/sample.wav'
    , encoding='LINEAR16'
    , sample_rate= 44100
    , 'languageCode': 'en-US'
)

retry_count = 100

operation = sample.async_recognize(language_code='en-US')

while retry_count > 0 and not operation.complete:
    retry_count -= 1
    time.sleep(10)
    operation.poll()  # API call

print(operation.complete)

print(operation.results[0].transcript)

print(operation.results[0].confidence)

for op in operation.results:
    print op.transcript
```

Then something like

```
for op in operation.results:
    print op.transcript
```